# Graph facebook com contador de comentários não funciona mais

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, facebook

Criei uma função em PHP que somava o número de comentários feitos no facebook e no wordpress para mostrar em cada post, mas acho que por causa das atualizações dos plugins do facebook, o código não funciona mais.

Já tentei criar um novo app no facebook para usar a versão mais atual, mas não tive sucesso e não tenho ideia se fiz alguma parte errada ou fiz tudo errado.

O código está atualmente assim, apenas o contador do facebook não funciona, mas o do wordpress sim:

```
function total_number_comment() {

      global $post;
      $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

      $filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$url);
      $json = json_decode($filecontent);

      $fb_count = $json->$url->comments;
      if ($fb_count == 0 || !isset($fb_count)) {
          $fb_count = 0;
      }
      $wp_count = (int)get_comments_number();

      echo $fb_count + $wp_count;
  }
```

E esse é o script:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'ID',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**Atualização**

Eu busquei mais informações sobre o meu erro e fiz novamente alguns testes e descobri que ainda está funcionando, só não como antes. Imprimindo diretamente a variável "$filecontent", eu obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
{
       "URL da postagem": {
          "og_object": {
             "id": "id",
             "description": "Descrição da postagem",
             "title": "Título da Postagem",
             "type": "Tipo da da Postagem",
             "updated_time": "Data da atualização da Postagem"
          },
          "share": {
             "comment_count": 6,
             "share_count": 37
          },
          "id": "URL da Postagem"
       }
}
```

Pois bem, dava erro na variável $json, então eu a removi e agora tenho este resultado. A questão agora é que não sei como chegar na parte que eu quero, que é o "***comment_count***".

Poderiam me dar um força, por favor?

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Qual o valor da variável "filecontent"? Edite a sua pergunta e adicione informações relevantes.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Desculpe pela falta de informações, irei melhorar agora.

Comment: Mas você precisa utilizar a função `json_decode` para converter a string contida em `$filecontent` em um objecto. Após isso, é possível aceder a propriedade `comment_count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode remover a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Essa função é necessária para converter a string contida em `$filecontent` em um objecto. Após isso, é possível aceder a propriedade `comment_count`.

Veja essa linha no seu código:

```
$fb_count = $json->$url->comments;
```

A propriedade `comments` não existe mais, basta observar o conteúdo da variável `filecontent`. Onde está a propriedade `comments`?

```
{
   "URL da postagem": {
      "og_object": {
         "id": "id",
         "description": "Descrição da postagem",
         "title": "Título da Postagem",
         "type": "Tipo da da Postagem",
         "updated_time": "Data da atualização da Postagem"
      },
      "share": {
         "comment_count": 6,
         "share_count": 37
      },
      "id": "URL da Postagem"
   }
}
```

Para obter o número de comentários, basta aceder a propriedade correta:

```
$json = json_decode($filecontent);
$fb_count = $json->$url->share->comment_count;
```

Comment: Minha nossa, completa falta de atenção da minha parte. Muito obrigado, terei mais atenção das próximas vezes.